# Laravel 5.4 updateOrCreate doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

**What i have:**

**Invoice** and **Invoiceitems** models with **hasMany** and **belongsTo** Relationship with eachother. Invoice can have many invoice items and one invoice item will belong to its invoice only. Basic one.

**Situation:**
Create works just fine. But when im trying to update an existing invoice with standard **createOrUpdate** Following happens.

1. if new row has not been created, it updates the existing invoices just fine.
2. if I added new invoice items, it gives out **Undefined index: id** error.

This is how Im using createOrUpdate:

```
$invoice->update($invoiceRequest->except('items'));

foreach($items as $item) {
        $invoice->invoiceitem()->updateOrCreate(['id'=> $item['id']],$item);
}
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Below is how my $items looks like

```
 {
 "id": "1",
 "invoiceable_id": "3",
 "fiscal_id": "2",
 "itemdue": "2018-01-19",
 "description": "a",
 "amount": "1000"
 },
 {
 "id": "2",
 "invoiceable_id": "2",
 "fiscal_id": "2",
 "itemdue": "2018-01-20",
 "description": "b",
 "amount": "1000"
 },
 {
 "id": "3",
 "invoiceable_id": "3",
 "fiscal_id": "2",
 "itemdue": "2018-01-19",
 "description": "c",
 "amount": "1200"
 },
 {
 "invoiceable_id": "1",
 "fiscal_id": "1",
 "itemdue": "2018-01-24",
 "description": "renewals",
 "amount": "100"
 }
```

Item with ids should be updated and last item(without id)should be created as new row. Someone Please let me know where exactly im missing. If you require more information, please let me know

Comment: How were you defining $items before hand in the controller (before the lines you provided)? I am in a similar situation and I'd like to see how you set yourself up with the updateOrCreate since it's new territory to me.

Comment: @Matthew  Mine is sorted, lets fix your problem. The main problem seem to be missing 'id' in invoiceitems for the new ones. You can either have a blank id field and save it or you can use
`'id' => isset($item['id']) ? $item['id'] : 0` like i did. This worked for me. Let me know if you my help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last element in the `$items` doesn't have `id`:

```
{
    "invoiceable_id": "1",
    "fiscal_id": "1",
    "itemdue": "2018-01-24",
    "description": "renewals",
    "amount": "100"
}
```

That's why `$item['id']` gives you the error.

You may want to check the data with something like this:

```
if (isset($item['id']))
```

Comment: it doesnt have the id because this item is newly added item. This is the issue i have. I wanted this item to be created. To create new item, id would not be necessary.

Comment: Well, you iterate over the collection and `$item['id']` throws the error. You need to add the check as I've shown in updated answer.

Comment: do i use IF with suggested condition to perform create and update separately? Can you please suggest me furthermore

Comment: @ashish if you want to create a new record when ID is empty, do this `'id' => isset($item['id']) ? $item['id'] : 0` instead of `$item['id']`